# How to handle animations + automatic container size

Tags: html, css

Ive got this animation which I want to size it automatically fitting the content. The headline always changes with daytime and user and I want to avoid that the headline container uses 100% of the available space for further animations.

With all automatic property the headline just pops up after 2.5 seconds.
So how do I handle this?

```css
.typewriter {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: animated-text 2.5s steps(30,end) 1s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes animated-text {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }

    to {
        width: fit-content;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="typewriter">Hello Admin</h1>
```

Comment: 'With all automatic property': what do you mean? And what are you trying to achieve? If you want the text to appear gradually, you can replace `width: fit-content;` with `width: 100%;`, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: @Thomas The headline is always different. Changes with name and time of the day. With: 100% uses all of the available space in this area. Which I want to avoid. (Ill edit this in the question also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to solve this with a grid on the parent element. We creae two colums, one with **auto** (it will shrink all the time) the second has **1fr**. And in the animation, change width of value from **fit-content** to **100%**.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.typewriter {
  grid-column: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  animation: animated-text 2.5s steps(30, end) 1s 1 normal both;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes animated-text {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="typewriter">Hello Admin</h1>
```

Comment: Probably would look better with a monospace font and the number of steps equal to the number of characters, but that works :)

Comment: In that case,  you need javascript to calculate each step. ^_^

Comment: Hehe, I'm not the one who asked, just someone who found it a good answer. Hopefully OP finds it helpful as well :)